# Is it possible for any double integral in rectangular coordinate to be transformed into double integral in polar?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For Example, I want to calculate the volume of solid within the region bounded by the x-axis, y=sinx and x = pi? In rectangular coordinate this double integral can be set up as $$\int_0^\pi\biggl({\int_0^{sin(x)}f(x,y)dy}\biggr)dx$$ How about in polar form?

Comment: Yes! You essentially just need to multiply by the Jacobian. https://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_variable_examples

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading this now.

Comment: If you have only $x$ and $y$ coordinates then everything is in the $x,y$ plane and you have only a region with area, no volume. On the other hand you can define surfaces by the formulas you mention, and those surfaces, the $x,y$ plane, and the surface where $z=f(x,y)$ bound a solid. Is that the question? You could use cylindrical coordinates. Alternatively, $f(x,y)$ is the density of a lamina and you want its weight. Those are different questions but your integral works for both.

Comment: I was asking this because I thought that any equation for a region in the rectangular coordinate can be rewritten into an equation pertaining to the same region in the polar form. For example, x^2+y^2=a^2 looks the same in polar, just set r=a. However I doubt there exists one for the region stated above, that is the region bounded by x-axis, y=sinx and x=pi.